# Jump to specific UITableView on application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:

Tags: iphone, uitableview, delegates, push-notification

When my app receives a Push Notification, application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: receives the data. When the user open the app from a notification, I want to jump to the last UITableView in the stack, to display the 'details' related to the Push Notification.

I am able to jump to the correct tab in the UITabBar.

Is there a way to Push views in that Tab from the App Delegate, or am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're already able to jump to the correct tab, you're almost there.

One way to do it would be to save off the push alert information into nsuserdefault... maybe in a form of a dictionary object in the "didReceiveRemoteNotification".  It's like of like save off a cookie web development for later use.

Then for the viewcontroller you're displaying in the tab that you jump to, you could do a check in viewWillAppear and see if you have anything stored in your nsuserdefault and grab the saved off notification data there and you can look up the corresponding data in your UITableViewDataSource.

Once you have that, you can call or do what ever you'd normally do had you selected the same data/object represented by a table cell and push the desired view (controller) into view.

Make sure to remove the object saved in NSUserDefault once you're attempted to push the view.

Comment: If I want the 'back' button on the detail screen to pop back through the normal sequence of screens, do I need to push each of the screens onto the stack? Can I push them all at the same time?

Comment: You'd have to push them one by one I believe.  But if you're going through all the trouble I'd reconsider the view hierarchy design.  Sounds too deep. Why not present a modal view when you get a push notification and show what you want to show that's related to the alert.